# Is scripted and declarative are equally powerfull?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

some say scripted is powerfull than declarative some say declarative is the recommended one. for a complex pipeline which type I need to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Declarative is the future.**

Declarative pipeline is a new feature that supports the pipeline as code concept. It improves the readability of pipeline code . This code is written in a Jenkinsfile which can be checked into a source control management system such as *Github* or *bitbucket*.

The scripted pipeline is a traditional way of writing the code. It uses stricter groovy based syntax because this is the first pipeline to be built on the groovy foundation. There is just one benefit. Scripted pipeline allows greater control over the pipeline. One can manipulate the flow of script extensively in this approach.

Currently , Declarative pipeline has a more strict and pre-defined structure. In future releases, declarative pipeline will inculcate the groovy syntax. If your CI pipeline is simple and short , go for declarative. If your requirements are complex and big , go for scripted.

Comment: all the available plugins support both the syntax are any limitations? any idea?